# Facebook page access token with Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I'm able to login my user using the LoginManager in the Android Facebook SDK and I get an access token.

Than, I retrieve the list of pages for which he is admin, and I can get the access token string for the page chosen by the user,

My objective is to allow the user to post as page but I can't create a valid AccessToken object for this.

I'm trying:

```
public void postMessage(String message, String pageId, FragmentActivity activity, GraphRequest.Callback callback, Context context) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", message);

    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if ( !pageId.equals("me")) {
        accessToken = new AccessToken(SettingsManager.getInstance(context).getFacebookAccessTokenPageId(), context.getString(R.string.app_id), pageId, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(accessToken, pageId + "/feed", params,
            HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    request.executeAsync();

}
```

But when I send the post I get an error. If I use the currentAccessToken without trying to force the page access token, I can post the message in the page but as normal user and not as page.

Does anybody know how to create an access token to be able to post as a page?

Thanks a lot
Emanuele

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Are you sure you requested the `publish_page` permission before requesting `/me/accounts`?

Comment: Hello, no, I requested publish_actions but not publish_page....I will give a try

Comment: Hello, that was the solution. Getting the "publish_page" permission did the trick!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can get this access token from Graph API explorer, the link given below...
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

log in with your account the page you admin and get the access token from here, and put it into your code.

or initialize the new access token in code with the help of this token..

```
  AccessToken token = new AccessToken("YOUR_TOKEN_HERE_FROM_EXPLORERE",
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId(),
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "manage_pages", "publish_pages"),
                null, AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SERVICE,
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getExpires(), AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getLastRefresh());
```